# Как получить все возможные части списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список, включающий в себя несколько вещественных чисел:

```
a = ['2.4', '5.2', '-10.6', '4.0', '7.8']
```

Мне нужно получить другой список, который состоит из всех возможных частей исходного списка. Частью списка я называю несколько элементов этого списка, которые идут подряд друг за другом. Думаю, это  может выглядеть примерно так:

```
b = [['2.4', '5.2'],
     ['5.2', '-10.6'],
     ['-10.6', '4.0'],
     ['4.0', '7.8'],
     ['2.4', '5.2', '-10.6'],
     ['5.2', '-10.6', '4.0'],
     ['-10.6', '4.0', '7.8'],
     ['2.4', '5.2', '-10.6', '4.0'],
     ['5.2', '-10.6', '4.0', '7.8'],
     ['2.4', '5.2', '-10.6', '4.0', '7.8']]
```

Порядок, в котором части списка **a** будут располагаться в списке **b**, не имеет значения. Количество элементов в списке **a** небольшое, обычно 10-20, но иногда может быть немного больше. Пожалуйста, скажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
len_ = len(a) + 1
for i in range(2, len_):
    for j in range(len_ - i):
        print(a[j:j + i])
```

```
len_ = len(a) + 1
b = [a[j:j + i] for i in range(2, len_) for j in range(len_ - i)]
```

Comment: Почему-то из девяти возможных находятся только шесть. Теряются: `['4.0', '7.8'], ['-10.6', '4.0', '7.8'], ['5.2', '-10.6', '4.0', '7.8']`. Можно ли это как-нибудь исправить?